# Trigger before insert on not concatenating columns

Tags: mysql

I have  create a trigger where the first column and second column would be concatenated into 3rd column.

```
USE `customer_1`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `Metric1_anpr_vega_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `Metric1_anpr_vega` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.image_id = CONCAT(NEW.camera_id,'-', NEW.id);
END

Id      camera_id   image_id
4567    236         236-0
```

( here i can't get id of the row when triggered it is '0' instead of 4567)

what trigger would get the ID value in image_Id after insert statment exceuted.

If i use after insert   I get this error - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: Use AFTER INSERT instead.

Comment: Well you can't get the inserted id before insert if its primary key, and cant use after insert to update the same table. One idea is to get the last id and then increment by one and set the image_id

Comment: can you tell me how can i get the last id.

Comment: try as `SET NEW.image_id = CONCAT(NEW.camera_id,'-', LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1);`

Comment: well you may use a query instead to get the last id and then increment it. Check here it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597467/mysql-after-insert-trigger-get-auto-incremed-value-update-field-value-after-ins

Comment: I used this in before insert trigger but the 4743 236 236-49848

Comment: Why use a extra column?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE `customer_1`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `Metric1_anpr_vega_BINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Metric1_anpr_vega` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.image_id = CONCAT(NEW.camera_id,'-', NEW.id);
END
```

Comment: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger